# Strange filename-like label appearing on desktop

Tags: nautilus, files, icons

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. The text "-PAXP-deijE.gif" appeared on my desktop, right after rebooting and logging in.

What is this label, why is it there and how can I get rid of it?

[image: This is where it appeared on my screen]

Comment: Any chance you could post a screenshot or something of this?

Comment: /home/david/Pictures/Screenshot from 2017-06-12 13:47:34.png

Comment: I do not have access to your system, please upload it to the question. If you can't do it directly to the question then just upload it somewhere like Imgur and provide a link.

Comment: I think it's a gif file in your desktop. Why can't you remove it?

Comment: Googling shows it might be from the online game war commander, so you might see it again later on.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a small transparent GIF image. Maybe you downloaded or copied it by accident. Right-click it with your mouse and delete it.

Comment: That worked! It removed it!